# I have simple HTML 5 code that I am trying to load on chrome but the player is greyed out and no controls are working

Tags: html, audio, mp3

I am using the latest version of Chrome 55+. I put the content below on index.html and the horse.mp3 file is in a subdirectory named audio.

when I open the index.html file in chrome, it shows the player, but it's greyed out and no volume controls are shown either. A similar example in w3schools works fine on chrome. the example at w3schools can be found at the link below :

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_audio_all

the code in index.html is as follows :

```
         <!DOCTYPE html>
          <html>
            <body>
              <audio controls>
                <source src=“audio/horse.mp3” type=“audio/mpeg”>
              </audio>  
             </body>
           </html>
```

Note :

- The horse.mp3 file plays fine offline. 
  The audio subdirectory exists and horse.mp3 exists within

Answer (score 2):

Try copy+pasting the following block:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <audio controls>
        <source src="audio/horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>  
    </body>
</html>
```

## Short Explanation

I switched your quotes to be only `"` instead of `“` and `”`.

## Long Explanation

The only thing I can see (and verify) is that you're using some funky quotation marks...

Instead of just using a `"` (a "standard" quotation mark), you are using a `“` and a `”` (a left double quotation mark and right double quotation mark). Browsers tend to not handle left and right double quotation marks as most people might expect (it's not a bug). Because of that, your audio tag probably has an incorrect `src` being set. For example, when I use the left and right double quotation marks and then inspect the source of the audio tag, I see the following:

```
<source src="â€œaudio/horse.mp3â€" type="â€œaudio/mpegâ€/">
```

Obviously, that's not the path you were looking for.

If you look at the unicode values for them (just copy+paste `“”"` into the search bar at [UnicodeLookup.com](https://unicodelookup.com)), you can easily see the difference between the three types of quotes.

I've set up a test demonstrating this and you can view it [here](https://rawgit.com/TheFlyingCaveman/StackOverflowAnswers/master/audioTagProblem/horseAudioTest.html). The element on the left has its source set with standard quotes, and the one on the right has its source set with the "special" quotes.